# Differences between a PortletRequest and a PortletResponse object

Tags: portlet

I understand that the Request objects (`RenderRequest`, `ActionRequest`, ...) contains the request we made, and the Response objects the response from the portlet...

But how, step by step everything works ?

If I take an example, I have a portlet with a little form. When I click onto the Send button, what is into the `ActionRequest` and the `ActionResponse` and when ? And after this first processing, what contains the `RenderRequest` and the `RenderResponse` objects?

Thanks for your help !

P.S: I don't use Spring MVC

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer you seek is available in the JSR specs; either the old one (http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=168) or the new one (http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=286) depending on your environment.

The specs are free to download and give a fair overview of the concepts.

Comment: I know you don't use Spring portlet MVC but you might try reading their documentation, at least the introduction: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/portlet.html